# sophos av path exclusion not working

Tags: linux, network-shares, anti-virus, sophos

I repeatedly get the `Unable to write to talpa socket` error because sophos free on ubuntu is trying to access a `sshfs` mount. I don't know what else I need to do to get sophos to *not* try to scan this mount (or anything under it).

```
root@myhost:~# /opt/sophos-av/bin/savconfig get ExcludeFilePaths
/home/myuser/mynetmount
root@myhost:~# /opt/sophos-av/bin/savconfig get ExcludeFilesystems
/home/myuser/mynetmount
```

And the periodic email root gets that has me trying to disable network scans:

```
An error classified as '0x3c: Unable to write to talpa socket' was detected in the file '/home/myuser/mynetmount/........' when attempting to open it at Fri Sep 28 01:14:00 2018 PDT -1500 (2018-09-28 08:14:00 UTC).  Access to the file was not allowed.
```

Ubuntu 16.04.5, SophosAV free-linux 9.15.0 VE3.72.1 (9.15.0.0.61)

(BTW: `network-shares` tag solely because I believe the SAV problem is incorrectly access network shares, not that I want to scan or set up network shares. Tangentially, the sshfs share is mounted with `drwxr-xr-x` and root can access most files in there. The remote site is not totally under my control, so there are files that the remote user cannot read.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exclude `/home/myuser/mynetmount/` to exclude a directory stem.

`/home/myuser/mynetmount` just excludes a file explicitly named "/home/myuser/mynetmount"

Comment: The trailing slash is all? Huh ... giving it a try, thank you.

Comment: Dang it, ***so*** frustrated by a missed opportunity to normalize/detect paths. \*sigh\*